# when i convert groupby object to dict the grouper objects are exhausted

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following code which takes a sorted list of tuples, applies a groupby and converts it to dict

```
from itertools import groupby
things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"), ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]
it = groupby(things, lambda x: x[0])
dict1 = dict(it)
print(dict1)
group_animal = dict1['animal']
print(list(group_animal))
```

the output is

```
{'animal': <itertools._grouper object at 0x7ff1f370db38>, 'plant': <itertools._grouper object at 0x7ff1f370db70>, 'vehicle': <itertools._grouper object at 0x7ff1f3685128>}
[]
```

the grouper object for animal is exhausted, even though i didn't cycle through it with a method. 
why does this happen?

Comment: the grouper object is not exhausted, that just the memory address of the object that you haven't iterated over yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the `grouper` that returned by the `it` and only get the `second` element of each value in the iterable.

The `it` returns a pair of objects; the key, and the group_iterable, and you only need the second element in each grouped items. That is `('animal', 'bear')`, you only need to get the `'bear'`, so get that by indexing like `item[1]`.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> things = [("animal", "bear"), ("animal", "duck"), ("plant", "cactus"), ("vehicle", "speed boat"), ("vehicle", "school bus")]
>>> it = groupby(things, lambda x: x[0])
>>> dict1 = {type_: [x[1] for x in thing] for type_,thing in it}
>>> dict1
{'animal': ['bear', 'duck'], 'plant': ['cactus'], 'vehicle': ['speed boat', 'school bus']}
>>> dict1['animal']
['bear', 'duck']
```

Comment: Okay. I will word it properly :)

Comment: I am told, the user had problem, maybe because that the iterator for 'animal' dies silently by the time you get the iterator for 'plant', and the the iterator of 'plant' dies, when you get to the 'vehicle'.  I think you  need to use up the iterator for 'animal' before groupby yields the one for 'plant', and so on